# how to monitor bytes in/out network trafic in c (linux)

Tags: c, linux, networking, monitoring

I wonder if there are functions for monitoring the number of bytes of network traffic that are going in/out on a linux machine.

I know that on windows you can use the PDH query data but I am not sure how to go about this on linux.

Any simple solutions or documents to work from would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`netstat -s` will give you a nice little summary of the packets in and out. You can change the formatting to suit your needs, or if you're looking for something where you can fine tune a little better, try `tcpdump` like most linux utils, you can get more info from their `man` pages, e.g. `man netstat`

Comment: Do you know how can I get this via a C code file. I dont want to invoke `system()` or parse output from `netstat -s`? any idea?

Comment: @Shiplu: You could download the source for netstat and find it. Likewise, the source code for ifconfig. GPL licensing is so nice...

Comment: @Zan, I have asked the question after reading `ifconfig.c`. But I didn't find any lib for net-tools so that I can link it. The only thing I found is `lib/interface.h` where `stuct interface` is defined. I need a way to use it.

Comment: @Shiplu: Link it? Link what? If I remember correctly it is just a few lines of code, not complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Monitor the output of `ip -s link`. (Or, if you want to work with Netlink on a low-level fashion, you will have to send RTM_GETLINK messages and will find the result in the IFLA_STATS64 attribute.)